# How to append a file with the existing one using CURL?

Tags: shell, curl, append

I've searched all over the web but couldn't find anything useful for this. Using CURL, I want to append content to a file which is already existing and named as `test.pls`. Can anyone please tell me how can I do it using curl. The commands I've tried are

```
curl http://192.99.8.170:8098/stream --output test.pls

curl -K --output test.pls http://192.99.8.170:8098/stream

curl -a  --output test.pls http://192.99.8.170:8098/stream
```

But all of above starts creating files from scratch.They don't keep the initial content of file Can anyone please help me!

Comment: Have you tried `curl http://192.99.8.170:8098/stream >> test.pls` ?

Comment: Ah great! Its working, Thanks! I rechecked with other file and its working properly.

Comment: `-a/--append` can be used only for `ftp` or `sftp` uploads - https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2020/04/13/curl-ootw-append/

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use the shell's appending output redirection (`>>`) rather than curl's `--output` option.

```
curl http://192.99.8.170:8098/stream >> test.pls
```

Comment: Just to be precise: '>' overwrites, '>>' appends. If the file does not exist, both commands  create it [tried with Windows/DOS, I suppose it's the same in Unix]

Answer (score 5):

A much easier and cleaner way is as follows:

```
curl -sS https://address.to.file.txt >> file-name.txt
```